# Turn NaN into a number

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am importing a dataset such as this one:

```
Year,Spain,Rest
2017,"1,688","5,787"
2016,"1,787","5,505"
2015,"1,826","5,187"
2014,"1,822","4,861"
```

And I need to turn these figures into numbers to display in a D3 graph. I have tried to use this two versions of code to do it but I still get NaN as an answer, so I do not know how to fix this:

```
d3.csv("stores.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
    t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  }
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Year = parseDate(d.Year);
    d["Spain"]= +(d["Spain"]);
    d["Rest"] = +d["Rest"];
    d["total"] = +d["total"];
    // ...
```

Instead of + I tried to use parseInt() in this way:

```
d["Spain"]= parseInt(d["Spain"]);
```

but it still does not work.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(d["Spain"])`? Try to expand your questions a bit. One thing though: I don't think you want to use `parseInt(string, radix)` because `parseInt("4,861", 10)` returns `4`. Maybe you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: The result of console.log(d["Spain"]) is NaN.

Comment: Okay, so it's going wrong before the `forEach`-function. Try to do indenting correctly and use better variable names. That's very helpful for debugging. While you're at it, I would suggest to change your question and code layout so it's more readable by others. Also, do a `console.log(d)` before the line with `d.Year ...`

Comment: @epascarello this is not a duplicate I think. Can you unmark it so I can post a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `,` from values before parsing

```
d["Spain"]= Number(d["Spain"].replace(',', ''));
```

Comment: Thanks! The only other thing I'd mention about your solution is that it assumes commas separate thousands instead of decimals. A little localization knowledge would be helpful here...

Comment: depending on the source of the data `,` may actually mean `.`

Comment: Yes, commas are separating thousands instead of decimals. I have tried with this solution but it says: "Typerror: d.Spain.replace is not a function".

Comment: @MichaelRo Which means you need to look into D3 docs, how to get data. If data is retrieved correctly and only a parsing issue then solution is correct.